# Register file changes to perform action

Tags: linux, files

I have the following problem: I make some automated changes in my webserver config (through a web interface) and I want to restart the apache. Since none of the actions are performed by root I cannot start the server directly.

My current workaround is to have a cronjob(every minute) for root that checks if a specific file exists (/tmp/restart.txt). If the file exists, it is deleted and the apache is restarted.

This can be invoked by other users by simply touching the file

```
$ touch /tmp/restart.txt
```

My question now is: Can I avoid the cronjob and somehow create a listener that gets invoked everytime the mtime of the file changes? This would be a better solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) to monitor file changes on our servers. It uses inotify, which is included in Linux kernels >= 2.6.13 and depends on Perl, but I guess this should be available if you are running a Linux box.

```
iwatch -c "File %f changed >> /tmp/changed.txt" -e modify /path/to/monitor
```

`-c` specifies the command to execute, `-e` specifies the events to watch for (all in the documentation). The `/path/to/monitor` can be a directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

cronjob doing this would be slightly more secure:

`find /path/to/httpd.conf -newer /tmp/ars.dat -exec "/path/to/apache.rc restart;" -exec "touch -m /tmp/ars.dat;"`

Putting the reference file somewhere other than tmp would probably be a good idea too.